# Another/separate value in Select Option

Tags: php, javascript, html, select, menu

I have a triple select option menu, that works fine now, but when I post/echo it in PHP both the option name and value are the same, so if I want a category that the name is Books, and that could be id=2 example.

I don't know how to put another value in the option, separate the name and value, can someone show me how???

Everything works fine, except I want to have another value than the same name I use to show option name. I hope you understand. :)

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var categories = [];

categories["startList"] = ["Wearing Apparel","Books"];

categories["Wearing Apparel"] = ["Men","Women","Children"];
categories["Books"] = ["Biography","Fiction","Nonfiction"];

categories["Men"] = ["Shirts","Ties","Belts","Hats"];
categories["Women"] = ["Blouses","Skirts","Scarves", "Hats"];
categories["Children"] = ["Shorts", "Socks", "Coats", "Nightwear"];

categories["Biography"] = ["Contemporay","Historical","Other"];
categories["Fiction"] = ["Science Fiction","Romance", "Thrillers", "Crime"];
categories["Nonfiction"] = ["How-To","Travel","Cookbooks", "Old Churches"];

var nLists = 3; // number of select lists in the set

function fillSelect(currCat,currList){

    var step = Number(currList.name.replace(/\D/g,""));

    for (i=step; i<nLists+1; i++) {
        document.forms['tripleplay']['List'+i].length = 0;
        document.forms['tripleplay']['List'+i].selectedIndex = 0;
    }

    var nCat = categories[currCat];

    for (each in nCat) {
        var nOption = document.createElement('option'); 
        var nData = document.createTextNode(nCat[each]); 
        nOption.setAttribute('value',nCat[each]); 
        nOption.appendChild(nData); 
        currList.appendChild(nOption); 
    } 
}

function init() {
    fillSelect('startList',document.forms['tripleplay']['List1'])
}

navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" ? attachEvent('onload', init, false) : addEventListener('load', init, false);    

</script>




<form name="tripleplay" action="" method="post">
<select name='List1' onchange="fillSelect(this.value,this.form['List2'])" size="5">
</select>

<select name='List2' onchange="fillSelect(this.value,this.form['List3'])" size="5">
</select>

<select name='List3' onchange="getValue(this.value, this.form['List2'].value, this.form['List1'].value)"  size="5">
</select>

<br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="next" />
</form>


<?php 
    if($_POST['next'])
    {
        echo $_POST['List1'].'<br>'.$_POST['List2'].'<br>'.$_POST['List3'].'<br>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: What are you expecting the PHP code to echo? The selection indexes?

Comment: I expect that echo for example: "1" I mean just the ID number for the option, just the ID instead of the name. But still wanna use the name to show it in option menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand your intention, but when a form is submitted, the value(s) of select boxes are delivered to the server.

The `label` property is being displayed in the UI (no need to append a text node).

If you set the `value` and `label` properties appropriately, you will be able to submit the form with any value that you want.

For example, the option construction code could be:

```
var nOption = document.createElement('option'); 
nOption.setAttribute('value',each); 
nOption.setAttribute('label',nCat[each]); 
currList.appendChild(nOption);
```

And you could get the label by using `this.selectedOptions[0].label`.

Notes:

1. The coding style that you are using is not very good.
2. You use inline event handling and do not separate business logic from UI, to name the main issues.
3. I suggest that you try some kind of JavaScript framework, such as jQuery, which will prevent you from reinventing the wheel and ease you development considerably, leaving you time to do actual work (you may consider a server-side PHP framework as well).

Here is a [**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/masteram/mNSJM/) that shows what I believe to be your desired effect.

### Edit:

Since you asked about a better approach, I will describe one possibility that slightly abstracts the logic and separates it from the UI.

This is not extremely useful in this type of situations, but it can help in more complex cases.

1. represent the data hierarchically.

   ```
   [{
       "id": 131,
       "label": "Wearing Apparel",
       "children": [{
           "id": 131,
           "label": "Men",
           "children": [{
               "id": 65,
               "label": "Shirts"
           }, ...
           ]
       }, {
           "id": 143,
           "label": "Women",
           "children": [{
               "id": 133,
               "label": "Blouses"
           }, 
           ...
           ]
       }]
   ]
   ```

   this way, you can encode a tree representation of PHP objects into JSON.
2. Create a jQuery objects that represents the list and generates the markup, since there is little use for it without JavaScript anyway.
3. Try to make your utility classes such that they could handle more general cases, so that in the future or as your current requirements change, you can still use it with minimal changes to your code.
4. Try to avoid inline handlers whenever possible (i.e, always).

I have created a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/masteram/Qa9EE/) example that does not go all the way, but still demonstrates some of those principles: it generates most of the markup on its own, handles the events itself, able to handle data with arbitrary and varying depth.

Comment: MasterAM how would you make the whole thing in jQuery, I know that it's not the best code for this, but can you help with to make it in jQuery? :D

Comment: First of all, does the code I posted do what you want? I want to make sure that I understand your intentions first.

Comment: I have tried to use it specific the code from jsFiddle and made a new php document but it's not working there. So i can't really say if its like that i want. But i want it to work like it does, only i want a custom ID for each of the options, so like books could have value="16"

Comment: Actually it's look like it works when i post it, my only problem is i can't see the text in on the select box? But in the code everything looks right. See on my website: http://dmweb.dk/tripleselect.php

Comment: And try to choose from the select menus and click the button

Comment: And if i take all of the code and make a new jsfiddle with your code, then it works :-S

Comment: I have mislead you about the text node. The spec says that the text content of the `<option>` is rendered, but some browsers take the `label` property, in the absence of text. I changed my fiddles. BTW, where is your `doctype`? use `<!DOCTYPE html><html>...`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem is

```
<option value="Wearing Apparel">Wearing Apparel</option>
```

that the value and the text(Wearing Apparel) is the same

First of all use another array sructure ( but json would be better )

```
categories["Books"] = [
                         ["Biography"],
                         ["Fiction"],
                         ["Nonfiction"]
                      ];
```

An your loop

```
    for (i=0; i<nCat.length; i++) {

        var nOption = document.createElement('option'); 
        var nData = document.createTextNode(nCat[i]);  // <------- use the "text"
        nOption.setAttribute('value',i);  // <------- use the index of the step
        nOption.appendChild(nData); 
        currList.appendChild(nOption); 

}
```

In this case

```
<option value="0">Wearing Apparel</option>
```

And your POST array will look like

```
Array ( [List1] => 0 
        [next] => Submit 
)
```

Where 0 is the ID of the "Wearing Apparel" element
... and 1 is ID of the "Books"

Comment: I understand, but what if i want to have a default ID? because I've have ID's from the database for each of them, so it have to be default id's :S

Comment: Use Javascript Objects:
 categories = { "Books": {
        1:"Biography",
        2:"Fiction",
        21:"Nonfiction"
} }

categories.Books["1"] will give you "Biography"

Comment: and  for(each in categories["Books"]){
    console.log(each +' : '+ categories["Books"][each]);
}

Comment: Can you try to do the whole code together because i can't make it work i've tried